# Ruby on Rails: How to implement 2 sortable columns ( pupil, mentor) for the same column in DB (user_profile)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In order to implement "sortable columns" in Rails, i used as example the framework build by Ryan Bates in [Railscast 228](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns).

I have an application where one "mentor" teaches one "pupil" during one "class". The identification data (first name, last name, date of birth) for both persons ( mentor, pupil) are saved in a single DB column "user_profiles".

To visualize the schedule of all "classes", the application renders a table:
    Pupil | Teacher | Class name | START | END.

While the "joins" logic in the controller (index method) is clear & simple, in the view ( V ), you need to specify the name of the DB column for "sortable". Here I encounter an ambiguous situation:

%th

= sortable ('Pupil', 'user_profiles.last_name')

%th

= sortable ('Mentor', 'user_profiles.last_name')

%th

Class name

%th

```
 ...
```

Do you have any idea how to instruct Rails to differentiate  between the two ?

(When click on "Pupil", sort those elements from "user_profiles.last_name" belonging to "Pupil". Idem for "mentor")

Thanks, 
  Ciprian

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you to use [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) jquery plugin for sorting. Its easy to integrate and use. It is also preferable as per UI design point of view.

Another thing, you should use different columns OR you can use `alias` OR you can apply sorting on set of columns.

Comment: Thank you! i'll look into jqGrid.                                                 I do not envision using separate columns for DB efficiency reasons. (DRY).

Comment: Problem solved : "Alias" inside the "join" in the controller.               .joins('LEFT JOIN user_profiles as mentors ON mentors.user_id = classes.mentor_user_id')   Thanks, RAJ